# Check if point(Lat,lng) inside a shape without javascript

Tags: c#

my situation

I have a C# windows service that listen to a port

the port recieve gps messages from gps devices including (lat,lng) Coordinates

i have a table with save shapes(Polygon,rect,circle,polyline)

saved as string(lat1,lng2|lat2,lng2|....) with a flag of the shape type
1- circle ,2- polygon .....
my question is 
in this windows service can i determine if the comming point lies within one of these shape

Table

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Points] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

[type] [int] NULL
```

Data

```
31.484893386890164,48.5595703125|31.278550858946534,47.493896484375|30.44867367928756,47.493896484375|30.609549797190844,48.592529296875|
```

i tried to convert string to geometry using

```
alter table yourTable add geographyColumn as geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),Long)+' '+convert(varchar(20),Lat)+')',4326)
```

thanks

Comment: What kind of database do you use? I´d recommend to make spatial queries there if your DBMS supports spatial datatypes.

Comment: it is sql server but points data saved as strings

Comment: can it be done with string fields or must change to sql geaometry

Comment: You can create a geometry on the fly from your coordinates. However you will need geometric support for the spatial operations, as a point-in-polygon-test is quite complex. You don´t want to do this on your own. Aside from database-handling you can also use some library such as GDAL or OpenLayers for this task.

Comment: can i try to convert these string points to geometry field on the fly in a stored procedure DECLARE @polygon geometry = 'POLYGON((Points))';

Comment: i searched for theses libraries but i can't understand how these will help

Comment: Why no one answering is it difficult or the question is not clear i now have 2 options  
  1- convert the points string to sql geometry field and use sql methoms
  2- use the library such as GDAL or OpenLayers (But i don't know how)

Comment: The question is simply too braod to be answered here. There are libs that do what you want, however explaining them is out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: ok just give names and i will try google for more details